# Python OpenCV iteration through contour errors

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using OpenCV to analyze a picture taken by a webcam.  I've then cropped, and converted the image to only black and white. I then want to find all the contours in the image, and identify the largest contour.

I'm running the code in a terminal window on a Ubuntu OS

Here is the relevant code :

```
num_contours, contours = cvFindContours(contourimg, # num_contours - # of contours
                          cvCreateMemStorage(0),    # and contours are the actual contours
                          sizeof_CvContour)         # cvFindContours() destroys contourimg

max_size = float("-inf")
max_contour = None

for contour in contours.hrange():           # contours.hrange() returns a list of all contours
    print contour
    size = abs(cvContourArea(contour))      # calculates the area of the bounding rectangle
    if size > max_size:                             
        max_size = size                     # update max_size if larger contour found
        max_contour = contour               # update max_contour if larger contour found
```

When I run the code I get different errors.  One is a Segmentation fault which the exits out of python and back into the terminal, but the other is:

```
 File "fitness.py", line 74, in boundingimg
size = abs(cvContourArea(contour))      # calculates the area of the bounding rectangle
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/opencv/cv.py", line 6741, in cvContourArea
return _cv.cvContourArea(*args)

RuntimeError:  openCV Error:
    Status=Bad argument
    function name=cvPointSeqFromMat
    error message=Input array is not a valid matrix
    file_name=/build/buildd/opencv-2.1.0/src/cv/cvutils.cpp
    line=53
```

Which I find is odd because I have a print statement of all the contours, and they all work fine, the for loop continues for a long time before throwing this error.  I'm not sure what is different about this contour from all the others.

Also, sometimes (not often) the code works, so the error doesn't happen each time.

Comment: is it done real time, in a video ?

Comment: yes, the image is captured from a video screen, but every frame of the video is not analyzed